# SignalR - How do I disable WebSockets

Tags: signalr

I upgraded to .NET 4.5, now SignalR seems insistent on using WebSockets in Firefox/Chrome - even though I'm only on Windows 7 which doesn't have a WebSocket Server.

The request obviously fails:

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://www.site.local/signalr?connectionData=
```

How do I force SignalR to forget about Websockets and use Long Polling, or is there a way of setting up Websockets for Windows 7 that I'm missing?

Update.... I'm using SignalR 0.4:

```
  <package id="SignalR" version="0.4.0" />
  <package id="SignalR.Hosting.AspNet" version="0.4.0.0" />
  <package id="SignalR.Js" version="0.4.0.1" />
  <package id="SignalR.Server" version="0.4.0.0" />
  <package id="SignalR.StructureMap" version="0.4.1" />
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I found the answer here:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client

Basically:

```
$.connection.hubs.start({ transport: 'longPolling' }, function() {
    console.log('connection started!');
});
```

Comment: Update to SignalR 0.4 and it'll only attempt websockets if the server supports it.

Comment: IF you're on .NETFramework 4.5 it will always try to use websockets since there's no good way to detect it right now.

Comment: Can't it be configured to try websockets just once, and if it fails revert to Long Polling rather than breaking things and requiring forced long polling?

Comment: Yes read the docs for more info https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-Client

Answer (score 10):

In order to disable a transport on the server side, you must use something like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports;
using Owin;
namespace MyApplication
{
    public static class Startup
    {
        public static void ConfigureSignalR(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // If using the global dependency resolver
            TurnOfForeverFrame(GlobalHost.DependencyResolver);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
        public static void TurnOfForeverFrame(IDependencyResolver resolver)
        {
            var transportManager = resolver.Resolve<ITransportManager>() as TransportManager;
            transportManager.Remove("foreverFrame");
        }
    }
}
```

The @reach4thelasers' solution only disable it in the client, but the client could re-enable the transport and connect.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking how to disable it on the server using asp.net core 3.1:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub", options =>
        {
            options.Transports =
                HttpTransportType.WebSockets |
                HttpTransportType.LongPolling;
        });
    });
}
```

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=dotnet#advanced-http-configuration-options-1