# SignalR and UploadFromStreamAsync have a different behaviour in IIS express and Azure Free WebSites

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asynchronous, signalr

I am currently developing a MVC 5 web application. I am facing a problem when uploading a blob (azure blob storage) in async and using SignalR 2.1.2.
My async controller ActionResult use this code:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext <ProgressHub> ();
context.Clients.All.newUpload ("Start Uploading ... Please wait");
await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync (model.Video.InputStream);
context.Clients.All.endUpload ("Upload complete");
```

Everything works fine asynchronously on IIS Express (async and SignalR) but not when I deploy it on Windows Azure Free Websites, SignalR and UploadFromStreamAsync stop working asynchronously.

Any idea?

**Edit 1 :**

Functionally everything works, the videostream is correct, the upload is successful, the only problem is that the task in not executed in asynchronous mode.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because Windows Azure Free Websites don't support WebSockets and SignalR will try to use it by default. Try taking a look at [SignalR - How do I disable WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994776/signalr-how-do-i-disable-websockets) and see if that helps.

Comment: Good idea. It's the first thing I checked. But in fact with Windows Azure Website if Websockets are not enabled signalR will then automatically use SSE.