# SignalR IE11 forewerFrame memory leak

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I have simple SignalR application with I hosted in IIS. When IIS is 8 from Win server 2012R2 IE11 was connected via WebSocket and everything work fine. But when I hosted on IIS 7.5 or IIsExpress 8 IE11 was connected vie forewerFrame and after 10 minutes memory consumed by IE was doubled.

Here Is my code 
SignalR config

```
public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
   app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration
   {
      EnableDetailedErrors = true,
      EnableJavaScriptProxies = true
   });
}
```

Hub

```
[HubName("testHub")]
  public class TestHub : Hub
  {
    [HubMethodName("update")]
    public void Update()
    {
      Clients.All.update(new TestData
      {
        Name = "Test1",
        Date = DateTime.Now,
        Value1 = 100,
        Value2 = 200,
        Value3 = 300,
        Value4 = 400,
        Value5 = 500,
        Value6 = 600,
        Value7 = 700,
        Value8 = 800,
        Value9 = 900,
      });
    }
  }

  public class TestData
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public int Value3 { get; set; }
    public int Value4 { get; set; }
    public int Value5 { get; set; }
    public int Value6 { get; set; }
    public int Value7 { get; set; }
    public int Value8 { get; set; }
    public int Value9 { get; set; }
  }
```

View

```
<h3>Homepage</h3>
@section scripts
{
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/signalR")
  <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")"></script>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      $.connection.testHub.on('update', function (item) { update(item); });
      $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
        setInterval(function() { $.connection.testHub.server.update(); }, 100);
      });
    });

    var count = 0;

    function update(item) {
      count++;
      $('#count').val(count);
    }
  </script> 
}
<span> count:<input type="text" id="count" value="0" /></span>
```

Does anybody knows what is wrong? I updated all nugets. jQuery 2.1.3, SignalR 2.2.0

Thanks

Comment: The time I used SignalR, as soon I read what that ForeverFrame madness was I disabled it straight away. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21337672/307976

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue with Forever Frame in IE: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/809

Try to force long polling.

Change your code accordingly:

```
  $.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'longPolling' }).done(function() {
    setInterval(function() { $.connection.testHub.server.update(); }, 100);
  });
```