# SignalR: getting error: WebSocket closed

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, signalr, azureservicebus, signalr-hub

I am working on project of Ionic with angular and AspNet with SignalR that have chat module.
I use SignalR for Chat.It's working smoothly but some time i am getting error as per below screen shot and because of that it's get stop working at all.
I have hosted my service on IIS and creating proxy and communicating with client and server. Here is sample

```
    (function () {
        angular
          .module('app')
          .factory('SignalRFactory', SignalRFactory);
        SignalRFactory.$inject = ['$rootScope', 'Hub', 'ionicToast'];
        function SignalRFactory($rootScope, Hub, ionicToast) {
            var signalRLocal = this;

            var serverURL = 'https://serivcerURL.com/signalr';

            //Hub setup
            var hub = new Hub('CommunicationHub', {
                rootPath: serverURL,
                listeners: {
                    'send': function (data) {
                        console.log("send " + data);

                    }

                },


                errorHandler: function (error) {
                //Here i am getting that websocket closed error
                    console.error(error); 

                }
            });


            signalRLocal.Connect = function (user) {
                console.log("SignalR Connecting as :" + user.UserName);
                hub.invoke('connect', user);
            };


            return signalRLocal;
        }
    })();
```

[image]

I have hosted service on IIS. I search for the solution and find something like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011288/signalr-2-2-0-websocket-error-connecting-to-hub)

I also try with above link solution by using "**long Polling**" as per below

```
Hub.connection.start({ transport: 'longPolling' });
```

But i don't want to use "long Polling" at all.
So can someone help me to figure out this issue without use of 'long Polling'.
Can someone tell me what configuration i have to do at client side or at IIS level.

Comment: Does the SignalR client try to reconnect after the connection is lost? Besides, you can try to [detect the reason for a disconnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#detecting-the-reason-for-a-disconnection). If possible, you can also call the ``Start`` method from your Closed event handler (``disconnected`` event handler on JavaScript clients) to start a new connection.

Comment: yes SignalR try to reconnect and it is also get connected

Answer (score 1):

As we said in comments, SignalR client will try to reconnect after the connection is lost. Besides, many factors (such as physical network interruption, client browser failure, server offline etc) can cause the connection lost, [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#connection-lifetime-terminology-and-scenarios) explains some disconnection scenarios, you can refer to it and find the possible causes of the issue.

Besides, as I mentioned in comment, you can call the Start method from your Closed event handler (disconnected event handler on JavaScript clients) to start a new connection to make client automatically re-establish a connection after it has been lost.

**edit:**

> The connection to ws://localhost:3156/signalr/signalr/connect?transport=webSoc‌​kets&clientProtocol=‌​1.5&connectionToken=‌​g8vpRv9ncVDjPIYB9UuE‌​pAAILEaOcTMTG9p46IA2‌​4 was interrupted while the page was loading.

Under "**Client disconnection scenarios**" section in [the article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#connection-lifetime-terminology-and-scenarios), you can find:

*In a browser client, the SignalR client code that maintains a SignalR connection runs in the JavaScript context of a web page. That's why the SignalR connection has to end when you navigate from one page to another, and that's why you have multiple connections with multiple connection IDs if you connect from multiple browser windows or tabs. **When the user closes a browser window or tab, or navigates to a new page or refreshes the page, the SignalR connection immediately ends because SignalR client code handles that browser event for you and calls the `Stop` method.***

Comment: Thanks for you kind of replay now i have little bit more error description in fire fox browser Error: The connection to ws://localhost:3156/signalr/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=g8vpRv9ncVDjPIYB9UuEpAAILEaOcTMTG9p46IA24 was interrupted while the page was loading.

Comment: but how to handle this. because of this error some feature get stop working.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying same and my client is in vue.js. I have changed below in `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/hub': {
        target: 'https://localhost:5001',
        changeOrigin: false,
        secure: false,
        headers: {
          'x-forwarded-proto': 'http',
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Previously i am trying `'x-forwarded-proto': 'https'`, when I changed to `http` its work.
`https://localhost:5001` is my .net endpoint and `http://localhost:8080` is my vue enpoint

Changed in `Startup.cs`below,

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHub<CardsHub>("/hub/cardsHub");
            });
```

Added below code in vue component

```
this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('/hub/cardsHub')
      .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the culprit was the wrong version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common

- the default one installed was 5.0.3
- but I was targeting 3.1.0

Downgrading to 3.1.12 fixed the issue with the connection.