# SignalR websockets not working on port 80

Tags: c#, websocket, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, iis-10

I am having an issue with all browsers not making a websocket connection over port 80 to my IIS 10 webserver. If I RDP into the server and browse to the application or if I use ssl (443) it works just fine. It does successfully fallback to longpolling but I would like to strictly use websockets.

I am running an asp.net mvc 5 app using the 4.6 framework. Websockets are enabled on the server. Has anyone else ran into this issue or have any suggestions to resolve it?

EDGE error: jquery.signalR-2.4.3.js:1893 WebSocket connection to 'ws://' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Firefox, Chrome error: jquery.signalR-2.4.3.js:1893 WebSocket connection to 'ws://' failed:

```
progress = $.connection.manifestHub;
console.log(progress);

progress.client.ShowProgress = function (message) {
  $('#ProgressMessage').width(message);
};

$.connection.hub.logging = true;
$.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'webSockets' }).done(function () {
      connectionId = $.connection.hub.id;
      $("#connectionId").val(connectionId);
      console.log(connectionId);
});
```

```
 var hubConfig = new HubConfiguration();
 hubConfig.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            
 app.MapSignalR(hubConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Your web server probably doesn't support WebSockets, probably because
> you're using a "proxy" server like ARR that just can't "route"
> WebSocket requests. Try disabling WebSockets on SignalR, if the issue
> persists it's a general SignalR issue, but at least you'll get a more
> specific error. If the problem stops, now you know it's a server
> problem.

Have you seen this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011288/signalr-2-2-0-websocket-error-connecting-to-hub)? This is an answer provided by @Andre Pena. I tried and this helped me. I think this might help you.

Comment: Websockets are enabled, and work over port 443. I don’t have a proxy server. It seems to be a browser issue but Im confused as to why it works over 443 and not 80. I will check out that post and see if it leads me down the right path.