# SignalR - How to declaratively disable transport protocol on server

Tags: signalr

Is it possible to declaratively disable some transport protocol like ForeverFrame in SignalR **on the server side**? I don't want to change any code but would like to do it in some config file...

I found how to do it code  but as mentioned this is not an option for me: [SignalR - How do I disable WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994776/signalr-how-do-i-disable-websockets)

Comment: Long story short - you would have to change code