# Failed connection handshake error when using AspNetCore.SignalR in ABP under IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, aspnetboilerplate

### My Environment

- .NetCore SDk - 2.1.300
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR - 1.0.0
- IIS - Version 10.0.12393.0 in Window Server 2016

### Sample Code for AspNetCore.SignalR

- I follow the instructions by link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/get-started?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio to complete a sample AspNetCore.SignalR chat code.
- I can run it successfully in Visual Studio.
- After that, I publish it to my server (window server 2016, IIS has websocket feature), and it also **works fine**. That means, my server environment support AspNetCore.SignalR well.

### Abp for AspNetCore.SignalR

- I download the ABP template code from ABP website
- Upgrade the .net core sdk to .net core 2.1
- Upgrade nuget packages
- Follow my above steps to add sample AspNetCore.SignalR chat code in the project.
- Run it successfully in visual studio

**The issue is, when I publish it to the server (same as my above server), and run it, it throws a error - AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext - Failed connection handshake.**

I have research it, but didn't get any solution. could you please help to look at it what the issue is?

I have push my project into github: https://github.com/lcyhjx/AbpExample, you can pull and run it (**Just run AbpExample.Web.Host**). It works fine in Visual Studio, but failed in IIS.

**The error detail:**

- Information: Normalizing '/chatHub' to 'http://localhost:6011/chatHub'.
- Information: WebSocket connected to ws://localhost:6011/chatHub?id=2zix_nPHODwLEv2p_4VCAw'
- Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned handshake error: An unexpected error occurred during connection handshake.'.

[image]

Comment: which version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR are you using ?

Comment: Does your web server support WebSockets? Try disabling websockets to understand if that's the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994776/signalr-how-do-i-disable-websockets

Comment: It can be firewall issue also

Comment: the version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR  is 1.0.0

Comment: yes, my server supports WebSockets, you can see my Sample Code for AspNetCore.SignalR works fine in my server

Comment: Hi vivek nuna, my Sample chat Code for AspNetCore.SignalR works fine in my server, it may not be a firewall issue.

Comment: In my case app crashed when mobile was running on 4G (WiFi was ok) and I was using HTTP only. After changing to HTTPS all was fine again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have addressed the issue. It's a code issue, in my code I have set

```
HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
```

If I comment above code, then all works fine in both VS and IIS.

Comment: But one I still don't understand is, why I set HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue, it works fine in VS but not in IIS.

Comment: Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

The same here, but a bit different: I ran the server in Rider and everything worked. I put it in another directory and I've got handshake errors. Removing the handshake timeout and it works everywhere.